colcon build error "Findserial.cmake" Not found in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
I am trying to colcon build a ros repository (which include some packages for controlling some step motors). After sourcing ROS in the root I ran colcon build, and it threw this error:
Starting >>> step_motor

--- stderr: step_motor                         

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package):

  By not providing "Findserial.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has

  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "serial", but

  CMake did not find one.



  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "serial" with any

  of the following names:



    serialConfig.cmake

    serial-config.cmake



  Add the installation prefix of "serial" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set

  "serial_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "serial"

  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been

  installed.

Failed   <<< step_motor [0.49s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.69s]

  1 package failed: step_motor

  1 package had stderr output: step_motor

  2 packages not processed

I think this means that I am missing the serial package as found in here, but I am not 100% sure. Unfortunately I live in a region with restricted internet access, and cloning from git almost never succeed for me. Can some kind soul confirm if this error means I am missing the serial pkg, and if so is there any workaround for installing this pkg? I do have a .zip copy for the serial package, but I am unsure how to install it manually.
Background information:
I used ros2 humble desktop installed from the debian pack. My ros2 is installed on Ubuntu 22.04, which is mounted as a virtual machine on Windows 10 using Virtualbox 7.0.

I have cloned it to my docker with Ubuntu 22.04 and ROS2 humble installed, it said that I'm missing the catkin cmake package. I think this serial package is meant for ROS1.
